# Heartfire Quotes in Arrested Development

Tags: arrested-development

In Arrested Development Season 4, Heartfire is sometimes subtitled while she is not facing the screen.  Is there any list of her dialog that I may read?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this, which you probably don't want to read but is unfortunately accurate, is "No".  No one has taken her specific subtitles out of the episodes she was in and put them online.  You will have to do that yourself.